# Adding spaces to the left of a string in c

Tags: c, arrays, string, function, char

How do you write a function to add extra blanks to the left end of a string to make it at least length n. If the string is already n characters or longer, it shouldn't change the string.

Assume the prototype is:

```
void padLeft(char a[], int n);
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're intended to code it at a relatively low level, you can follow these steps.

1. Get the current length with `strlen()`, call this `len`. If it's already at least `n` characters long, just return.
2. Use `memmove()` to copy from `str[0]` to `str[n - len]` (for `len + 1` bytes). The `memmove()` function, unlike `strcpy()`, handles overlap correctly.
3. Fill the first `n - len` characters with spaces, using `memset()`.

---

For example, let's say you want to pad the string `"pax"` out to seven characters. It will follow the steps below (where `.` is the null terminator at the end, `?` means any character):

```
0123456789    Positions within string.
pax.??????    Initial situation, len = 3, n = 7.
????pax.??    memmove (str + 7 - 3, str, 4);
    pax.??    memset (str, ' ', 7 - 3);
```

---

Okay, that's where I want you to stop reading until you've gone away and tried it yourself. Once you've done that *and* debugged it *and* got it working to your satisfaction, compare it with what a professional coder might come up with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void padleft (char a[], int n) {
    size_t len = strlen (a);
    if (len >= n) return;
    memmove (a + n - len, a, len + 1);
    memset (a, ' ', n - len);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    static char buffer[1000]; // usually a no-no, but fine for testing.

    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Usage: padleft <string> <size>\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int sz = atoi (argv[2]);
    strcpy (buffer, argv[1]);

    padleft (buffer, sz);
    printf ("[%s] padded to size %d is [%s]\n", argv[1], sz, buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's great! I didn't know about memmove and memset. Thank you so much!

Comment: @JimmyKelly:- You can accept this as answer if that helped you! :)

Comment: I'm new to C so I'm still learning. How would you use the same approach to  add spaces to the right? just curious

Comment: @Jimmy, adding to the end is easier since you don't have to move anything, it would go something like: `size_t len = strlen (buff); if (n > len) { memset (buff+len,' ', n-len); buff[n] = '\0'; }`. Or `size_t len = strlen (buff); if (n > len) sprintf (buff + len, "%*s", n - len, "");`

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the printf function like this:

```
printf("|%10s|", "Hello");   //Will add spaces to the left of Hello
printf("|%-10s|", "Hello");   //Will add spaces to the right of Hello
```

**[IDEONE DEMO](https://ideone.com/16e6Gx)**

Comment: Yeah that works nicely but how would I change that number 10 to any number the user inputs? say the user inputs n=5 and i want 5 spaces to the left of it.
printf("|%ns|", "Hello"); won't obviously work. Any other way?

Comment: @JimmyKelly:- See the approach given by paxdiablo. Thats the one to proceed with +1

Answer (score 0):

Using functions like `memmove` and `memset` is a good idea,however it's good to solve it manually,to know how it works.The general idea is to shift the elements of the string to the right,and add whitespace to the left end.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int appendSpaces(char *str,unsigned int n);

int main(void)
{
    char str[20] = "abc";
    appendSpaces(str,2);
    printf("%s\n",str);
}

int appendSpaces(char *str,unsigned int n)
{
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    if( n >= len )
        return 0;
    size_t y = len , x = y;
    while( n-- > 0 )
    {
        while( x-- )
        {
            str[x+1] = str[x];
            if( x == 0 )
                break;
        }
        str[x] = ' ';
        str[y+1] = '\0';
        x = ++y;
    }
    return 0;
}
```